# Creating JSON array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I need some help here. This code gives expected result but fails when the value of the Id is not an integer

```
const obj = {
    "id": "[1, 2, 3]",
    "priority": "High",
    "assignto": "DanTest",
    "comment": "This is a test"
};

const result = JSON.parse(obj.id).map(e => {
  const copy = {...obj};
  delete copy.id;
  return {
    id: e,
    ...copy
  };
})
console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "priority": "High",
    "assignto": "DanTest",
    "comment": "This is a test"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "priority": "High",
    "assignto": "DanTest",
    "comment": "This is a test"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "priority": "High",
    "assignto": "DanTest",
    "comment": "This is a test"
  }
]
```

Fails if

```
const obj = {
    "id": "[Jay, Dan, Boy]",
    "priority": "High",
    "assignto": "DanTest",
    "comment": "This is a test"
};
```

This returns an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token j in JSON at position 1
>       at JSON.parse ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So technically because `id` looks like an array but it is a `string`, you need to parse it first with `JSON.parse()`, then using `map()` you can create a new array with the expected structure.

I guess this can work for you:

```js
const obj = {
    "id": "[1, 2, 3]",
    "priority": "High",
    "assignto": "DanTest",
    "comment": "This is a test"
};

const result = JSON.parse(obj.id).map(e => {
  const copy = {...obj};
  delete copy.id;
  return {
    id: e,
    ...copy
  };
})
console.log(result);
```

Or in IE without arrow function:

```js
const obj = {
    "id": "[1, 2, 3]",
    "priority": "High",
    "assignto": "DanTest",
    "comment": "This is a test"
};

const result = JSON.parse(obj.id).map(function(e) {
  const copy = {...obj};
  delete copy.id;
  return {
    id: e,
    ...copy
  };
})
console.log(result);
```

Read further here:

1. [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
2. [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)
3. [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful

Comment: @jerifortune If the solution meets your requirement and works fine for you, please cosider upvoting and accepting as the answer, thank you!

Comment: the code works for me if id is an integer but fails when when the id is string for example "id": [Jen, boy, dad] produces this error              SyntaxError: Unexpected token j in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/Main.js:8:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)

Comment: @jerifortune The reason behind that is you are using wrong syntax for array of strings, it should like `"id": ['Jen', 'boy', 'dad']`. You forgot to include `'` or `"` around the strings in the array, other than that it's just simply not a valid JSON object.

Comment: Hi @norbitrial, IE browser is not recognizing arrow function (=>). How can I rewrite the above function without the arrow function? Thanks

Comment: @jerifortune Just edited my answer, change from `(e) => {}` syntax to `function(e) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Initial data

```
var data = {
    "id": "[ 1, 2, 3]",
    "priority": "High",
    "assignto": "DanTest",
    "comment": "This is a test"
}
```

Solution

```
var newObjList =  [];
// deserialize JSON string to array
var dataConverted = JSON.parse(data.id);
//loop thru ids
for(var i = 0; i < dataConverted.length; i++) {
   //create new object for each id and assign values
   var obj = {
     id: dataConverted[i],
     priority: data.priority,
      assignTo: data.assignTo,
      comment: data.comment
   }
   //add object to a list
   newObjList.push(obj);
}
```

Then to access you can serialize JSON to a string

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(newObjList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this the following way:

```js
let obj = {
    "id": "[ 1, 2, 3]",
    "priority": "High",
    "assignto": "DanTest",
    "comment": "This is a test"
};
let objArr = JSON.parse(obj.id).map((x) => {
    return {
    "id": x,
    "priority": obj.priority,
    "assignto": obj.assignto,
    "comment": obj.comment
    }
});
console.log(objArr);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have access to newer ES2015+, you can simply do the following.

```
const newJson = oldJson.id.map(id => ({ ...oldJson, id }));
```

Or in ES5

```
const newJson = oldJson.id.map(function(id) { 
   return Object.assign({}, oldJson, { id: id });
});
```